# Lightbox_Me fadeOut Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, lightbox, fadeout

I have been trying to set up LightBox_Me for a client. The idea is for an Age Verification overlay to appear when the page loads which asks "Are you over 18?". Yes or No. Upon clicking yes, the overlay disappears.

The Overlay will fade in, but I cannot work out how to get it to fade out.

[Jive Release Notes with fadeOut support](https://community.jivesoftware.com/blogs/jivespace/2010/07/07/lightboxme-updated-to-22-with-some-bug-fixes-and-a-new-feature)

The above link shows that the there should be support for fadeOut.

I have tried implementing this into the lightbox_me.js file which is where all of the appear effects are, but to no avail.

I have also tried implementing it into my age verification script, which is:

```
$(window).load(function () {
// Age Verification
if(!$.cookie('legal-age')){
    $('#verify').lightbox_me({
        centered: true,
        closeClick: false,
        closeESC: false,
      //disappearEffect: fadeOut,
      //overlayDisappearSpeed: 300,
      //lightboxDisappearSpeed: fast,
        overlayCSS: {background: '', opacity: 0},
        closeSelector: '.v-yes',
        onClose: function(){
            $.cookie('legal-age','yes', {domain: '*Snip*', path: '/'});
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

The code above shows the 3 lines of code that should determine the fadeout animations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the 'latest' build (which is over two years old now), then those particular options are no longer available. They were originally added [over three years ago](https://github.com/buckwilson/Lightbox_me/commit/0db4028f90c42de083339269acea59c146040521), and subsequently [removed 9 months later](https://github.com/buckwilson/Lightbox_me/commit/297ce3a313a64cd46cddc4754ded9c402a304838).

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a graceful built-in way to fade out a `lightbox_me` lightbox any longer. If you are comfortable with jQuery you could probably re-add the code that was removed from that [first commit](https://github.com/buckwilson/Lightbox_me/commit/0db4028f90c42de083339269acea59c146040521), although I suspect it was removed for good reason.

**A couple of other things worth pointing out:**

Unless you're using a pre-1.9.x version of jQuery, the script is going to error out around **line 31** - you'll want to replace this:

`ie6 = ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7);`

...with this:

`ie6 = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE 6/);`

And if you do intend to re-add these effects, you'll want to make sure your values for  `disappearEffect` & `lightboxDisappearSpeed` are declared as strings, otherwise it will error out:

```
$('#verify').lightbox_me({
    centered: true,
    closeClick: false,
    closeESC: false,
    disappearEffect: 'fadeOut',
    overlayDisappearSpeed: 300,
    lightboxDisappearSpeed: 'fast',
    overlayCSS: {background: '', opacity: 0},
    closeSelector: '.v-yes',
    onClose: function() {
        $.cookie('legal-age','yes', {domain: '*Snip*', path: '/'});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to be the correct answer. I havent tried it but it makes perfect sense. I ended up ditching the lightbox and just called the div using JQuery instead. No real difference apart from the fade in animation which the client wanted removed. It was just extra code that was unnecessary.

Comment: @Curley5959 Glad you got it sorted. lightbox_me is a really handy script and I use it regularly, but it definitely has its place.